# FileNotFoundException when I try to read txt file via Command Line

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments, filenotfoundexception

I built a project in eclipse that uses a txt file. the file is located in the main folder project.

I get the file name as argument via command line, and I get `FileNotFoundException`. I try to use `Scanner` Object and get the file name as input from eclipse.. and it's worked. (I insert only the file name : file.txt  . not the full path)
so why via the eclipse it's work and with command line not?

thank you!
this is the exception:

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: bigMaze.txt (The system cannot find the file spec
    ified)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
            at BFS.BFS.readFile(BFS.java:43)
            at BFS.BFS.InsertMaze(BFS.java:57)
            at BFS.BFS.StartMain(BFS.java:16)
            at search.main(search.java:20)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at BFS.BFS.InsertMaze(BFS.java:62)
            at BFS.BFS.StartMain(BFS.java:16)
            at search.main(search.java:20)
```

Comment: plaese show some code and a stack trace

Comment: This looks like a CWD problem... Are the path to your file *relative*? If so, have you `cd`'d into the correct directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running from the command line, try placing the file in the same directory as the .class file

```
ProjectRoot
       bin
          file.txt
          program.class
       src
```

If the program is running from eclispe, then the file should go where you originally had it. directly under the project root.

This is all considering your running the program with `String filename = "file.txt";`

Comment: Thank you! 
I add the text files to the BIN folder, and it's working!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is regarding pathname of your txt file. In case of command prompt you have to provide full path like: "MyComputer://D/yourFile.txt" but using eclipse you can give just "D://yourFile.txt". It will work.